# BigSur upgrade breaks the share menu option in Safari

Tags: finder, safari, safari-extensions, big-sur

I've just upgraded to Mac OS X Big Sur (Version 11.01) from Catalina. Normally in the browser or finder you can select the 'Share' to send information to another application. For example, if browsing a site and want to save the information I would typically select the 'Share to' icon, select Notes and then my information would be saved.

After upgrading to Big Sur I've hit the following issues:

1. Share menu in Safari is empty
2. Selecting the 'More' option pops up
   the Extensions preference which is all blank

[image]

Now if I try the path of going to the Safari option to add an extension the new functionality in BigSur pops open the App Store. I can select an option and after installing it then says to return to the Extensions 'management' screen but nothing is able to be selected or activated.

Net result - stuck !

Does anyone have any suggestions

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the Application from the AppStore?

Comment: Tried an application restore but no change to the Extensions menu

Comment: How about under a fresh user account?

Comment: Try temporarily removing the plist file associated with Share menu extension, and let Big Sur rebuild it by restarting your Mac. I'd recommend you save the original plist file to your desktop, so if anything stuffs up, you can always return it. The plist is located in the file directory `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.prefences.extensions.ShareMenu.plist`. Once you've removed it from this folder, restart your Mac and let it rebuild the plist by itself. Occasionally it'll need an application to rebuild it (such as `System Preferences.app`), if a restart doesn't rebuild it. Good luck

Comment: That menu doesn't belong to Safari, it's really `System Preferences > Notifications > Sharing`. And like the others are saying, look for corruption (or xattr) on the corresponding plist.

Comment: @GrantSayer did you try removing the plist for the sharemenu and letting macOS Big Sur to recompile it?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to reinstall macOS BigSur from the recovery but without deleting your drive (so you don't loose your stuff)

The good thing is that inside of macOS the System and user partition is separated so you are not forced to touch the user partition while reinstalling the system!

Comment: How would reinstalling macOS solve the problem the OP has?